Ascertain the PID of an instance of Microsoft Word running on MAC OS Sonoma 14.4.1 that was spun from java
I have an Swing App (Java 19) running on MacBook PRO, In The App The User Opens A 
Microsoft 
Word .docx file for editing, I am Opening it with 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD) 
CMD[0] = "open";
CMD[1] = "-a";
CMD[2] = "Microsoft Word";
CMD[3] = inc.getAbsoluteFilePath(fileName);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD);
PID = p.pid();

Microsoft Word Opens The File w/o any Issues.
The App in the meantime is monitoring the File for Size and Last Time Stamp as Well As If The Instance of Microsoft Word is still Running. (This part Works Great on Windows As I am Able to Determine if the File Is Locked, Not On Mac)
I check the PID against the 
PS -elfT however I do not see the PID the Process p returned, I am Assuming it is the 
PID of the "open" process and not the resulting MS Word process.

Can anyone recommend the best way to determine when the user has released the File
So the APP can process the saved File.
Any Help Would be appreciated.
Regards

Why are you using the ancient runtime.exec() and not the modern ProcessBuilder and Process classes?

Maybe try Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fileName)); and a WatchService for ENTRY_MODIFY events.

Fix the formatting of your question. It is hard to read.

Thanks, Eiter approach on Mac does not alert the App user that the Word Doc was closed.

As User could open the Word Doc , close it w/o making any changes. I am required to detect this doc is no longer in use and save it to a Server. I don't see that Word places an OS Lock on the document it opened.  So I don't see how to programmatically determine the document is no longer open. Thoughts?

Thanks for the Advice.
Turns out In Mac OS the program "/usr/sbin/lsof absolute Path of File" provides results of file that is open
Using ProcessBuilder to Execute "/usr/sbin/lsof absolute Path of File"
Worked as Expected.
My App is able to detect when the File Opened By My App In MS Word is In Fact Open or Not.
Regards
